# Merge Conflict Cases in Git

Tags: git

I have just now started using Git and previously used CVS for versioning.

Can someone explain me how to deal with merge conflict cases in Git? Also what is the standard procedure to follow in such cases.

I faced a situation after doing the below steps,

1. I had committed some files into my local repository using `git add` and `git commit`
2. Later when I tried to push my local repo changes to a remote repo, it fails with a *non-fast-forward error* and prompts me to pull before pushing.
3. So I tried `git pull` to fetch the latest from remote repo into my local repo. Pull failed and said there were merge conflicts.

Let's assume I pull from the remote into my local repo and then do step 1 (committing files). What happens if someone else pushed their changes before I push to the remote repo. I believe push ending with merge is a usual case. How to deal with these cases?

I assume pull involves fetch + merge. In my case automatic merge seems to have failed. What do I have to do in the above case? Please also tell me how to avoid getting into such situations?

Comment: It's worth checking out the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book) as a first port of call. It has a really good [chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#) which covers merging.

Comment: @uncollected, Thanks for the information. Definitely I need some guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick list of how I do my git commits:

1. `git clone <repository url>`
2. make changes
3. `git stash`: this stashes your uncommitted changes away in a temporary cache (and temporarily removes them from the working directory, so you have a clean copy)
4. `git pull` to get latest repository version
5. `git stash pop` applies stashed changes to local repository (and remove them from the stash); this might produce conflicts, just like a merge or rebase
6. fix any conflicts
7. `git add <changed files>`
8. `git commit`, using `-m` to provide a short message or leaving it out to open an editor
9. `git push` to publish your changes to the remote

They way to avoid the problem you hit is to stash your changes before a pull, then pop the stash after pull is complete.

Comment: what you're doing is effectively a `git pull --rebase` without committing first (and using more commands)

Comment: @hotSauce.Open, Thanks for sharing your experience. As I am new to this GIT, I am not that much aware of stashing. I will go through it. Your answer is really helpful. Meanwhile please tell me what I have to do if I caught into situation explained in my case ?

Comment: As Nevik said above, there is a more straight-forward way to do what I'm doing by instead of stashing, just use git pull --rebase. In the situation you're currently in, do a git stash, git pull, then git stash pop.

Answer (score 3):

When you have conflicted files git will insert conflict markers into each conflicted file.  The conflict markers contain the code from both branches like this:

```
 <<<<<<<<< LOCAL_BRANCH_NAME
 local code goes here
 ==========
 merge branch code goes here
 >>>>>>> MERGE_SHA
```

When you do git status you will see these files have status "both modified", these are conflicted.  Technically all you need to do to resolve these is do `git add file`, but obviously if that's *all* you do your code will be messed up.

The easiest way to solve conflicts is using `git mergetool`.  Run `git mergetool` when files are conflicted and git will ask you which merge tool you want to use, it supports a long list my preferred tool is kdiff3.  `git` will then walk you through each conflicted file, using a 3 way diff if your tool supports it (highly recommend that, it makes things a lot easier).

As uncollected suggesting in a comment, reading the [git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#) is a must when you're starting out.